# Facebook API doesn't return the user's shared story after 10 Feb 2015

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to get user's wall post(photo or video) shared from facebook pages.
I am using graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed (or user-id/posts) option to get this data via  read_stream permission. (Is there any other option available for the required task?)
It works before 10 feb, 2015. 
The problem is that it doesn't return the user's shared story (shared picture/video from fb page) anymore. It shows the user's status and uploaded pics/video post only. 
The older post (shared pix/video) are still visible. But no new posts are showing on fb graph API explorer. How can I get the user's shared story (shared picture/video from fb pages) from facebook?

Comment: Why do you need the stories a user shared from pages?

Comment: Working on Facebook app that users can subscribes.

Comment: Don't understand why that means that you need to know what posts a user shares